# invoking Meteor methods cause internal server error[500]

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm invoking my methods from main.js(server) then i used Meteor.call() on main.js(client) and then I recieved an internal error[500]

here is my file structure

[image]

this is the console error

[image]

main.js(**client**):

```
import Tasks from '../imports/api/task.js';
import './main.html';

Template.tasks.helpers({
    tasks() {
        return Tasks.find({},{sort: {createdAt: -1}})
    }
});

Template.tasks.events({
    'submit .add-task': function(event){
        var name = event.target.name.value;
        Meteor.call('addTask', name);


        return false;
    },
    'click .delete-task': function(event){
        if(confirm('Delete Task?')){
            Meteor.call('deleteTask', this._id)
        }

    }
});
```

main.js(**server**):

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import '../imports/api/task.js';


Meteor.startup(() => {
  // code to run on server at startup
    Meteor.methods({
        addTask: function(name){
            if(!Meteor.userId()){
                throw new Meteor.Error('Access Denied');
            }
            Tasks.insert({
                name: name,
                createdAt: new Date(),
                userId: Meteor.userId()
            });
        },
        deleteTask: function(taskId){
            Tasks.remove(taskId);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: What is the `error` in the server console?

Comment: @tomsp Tasks is not defined. I added the console error screenshot

Comment: @tomsp thanks bro i focused to much on looking at console.log error. i didnt notice the server console error

Comment: But when Tasks is not defined, then the import of the collection is the problem.

Comment: @tomsp ya. i though doing import '../imports/api/task.js'; will implement all variables inside that file, and i need to specify it like this import Tasks from '../imports/api/task.js';

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your methods on server side only.

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
  // code to run on server at startup
    if(Meteor.isServer){
        Meteor.methods({
            addTask: function(name){
                if(!Meteor.userId()){
                    throw new Meteor.Error('Access Denied');
                }
                Tasks.insert({
                    name: name,
                    createdAt: new Date(),
                    userId: Meteor.userId()
                });
            },
            deleteTask: function(taskId){
                Tasks.remove(taskId);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: i define them on server main.js check the file structure

Comment: my server and  client main.js is in different folder and file,

Comment: Then you are importing the Task collection correctly

Answer (score 1):

Ok I already found out the answer, I though doing `import '../imports/api/task.js';` in main.js(server-side) will include all the variables inside of it, the answer is that I need to this `import Tasks from '../imports/api/task.js';` can someone explain the differences?